# Vuetify.js and date-picker watch doesn't trigger on month

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Running `Vue.js` and `Vuetify.js`.

I'm testing the `data-picker` and the `watch` method for triggering events on change of month. However, it only seems `watch` is noticing change of `year`, and not `month`.

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>

    <v-date-picker ref="picker" v-model="date" :picker-date.sync="pickerDate" type="month"></v-date-picker>

  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      pickerDate: null,
      date: null,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    pickerDate(val) {
      console.log(val)
    }
  }
});
```

Codepen example shown here: https://codepen.io/alfredballe84/pen/varGWe?editors=1111

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should watch `date` not `pickerDate` but it's will trigger `yyyy-mm`

```
  new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data() {
        return {
          pickerDate: null,
          date: null,
        };
      },
      watch: {
        date(val) {
          console.log(val)
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, at least with current Vuetify. `v-date-picker` 's v-model changes when the user selects a date and picker-date changes when the user browses in the picker to different month.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem by changing the `v-model="date"` 
to:

```
v-model="pickerDate"
```